# how search a word list inside a string?

Tags: python

I'm very nob from python and for now i want search a world list inside a string and if any of these words being inside of string return false and if every words nothing inside of string return True

for example:

```
filter_list = [ball,sport,music,running,swimming,jim]

string = "i going for jim everyday"
```

so result must be false because jim is in string and if wasen'n should be True

is very important to me , if you use for loop ,loop should be run just once not 6 times.

Comment: Anything you have tried ?

Comment: You need quotes around the words in `filter_list`.

Comment: Split the string into words. Then use the `every()` function to test that every word is not in `filter_list`.

Comment: @Barmar I think that should be `all()`

Comment: Yes, I think they were referring to all(), but you can always use "not any(item in list for item in splitted)".

Comment: Please check & follow best practices for asking questions in Stackoverflow. Asking for code is not encouraged in stack-overflow !

Answer (score 4):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
filter_list = ["ball","sport","music","running","swimming","jim"]

string = "i going for jim everyday"


def filter_words():
    for word in filter_list:
        if word in string:
            return False
    return True

print(filter_words())
```

Comment: not actually,print(string) should be False

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(string, lst):
   return True if len(tuple(filter(lambda x: x in lst, string.split(" ")))) == 0 else False 

filter_list = ["ball","sport","music","running","swimming","jim"]

string = "i going for jim everyday"

print(check(string, filter_list))

>>> False
```